# How can I solve huge performance issues when comparing and updating data with java?

Tags: java, performance, ms-access, prepared-statement

I want to compare two lists with objects of the same type which have about 30 Values. When there are differences the new Value should be updated to the database.
The part where my code gets really really slow, like one update every minute, is when the data should be updated.

reading all the datasets from db and Excel is fast. But when it comes to the below code it already starts to nearly stop after 200 datasets.

I can't provide a complete code for you since the method getLists() calls a lot of functions which would be far too much code in my opinion. But maybe you can still help me with my problem since the relevant part where the performance gets low occurs at the given code.

Maybe somehow a lot of objects getting created or something like that?

EDIT: I run the program with IntelliJ. When I close the running application and start it again it loads the already slowly loaded datasets from the previous time really fast but then slows down again. Maybe something with the cache is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainWindow_Controller {

List<Pensioner> pensionerDB = new ArrayList();
List<Pensioner> pensionerExcel = new ArrayList();

Boolean checkStatusChange = false;
String pathDB = "";

@FXML
private TextField tfDBPath;

/**
 * This method compares the pensioners from database with the ones from the Excel head file.
 * Based on matching pensionInsuranceNumbers the method checks if the status is different.
 * If it is different, the status gets updated.
 *
 * @param event
 */
@FXML
void getStatusChange(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException {
    String type = "Statuswechsel";
    if (pensionerDB.isEmpty() || pensionerExcel.isEmpty()) {
        getLists();
    }

    pathDB = tfDBPath.getText();
    //load pensioners from database in first list
    pensionerDB = array[0];

    //load pensioners from excel head file in second list
    pensionerExcel = array[1];

    //compare pensionInsuranceNumber from first list with pensionInsuranceNumber from second list and move missing datasets to third list
    List<Pensioner> result = new ArrayList();

    Database.connect(pathDB);

    //iterates over the two lists with pensioners in database and pensioners in Excel files and adds the dataset with matching pensionInsuranceNumbers into the result list.
    for (int i = 0; i < pensionerExcel.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Processing Excelrow Number: " + i);
        for (int j = 0; j < pensionerDB.size(); j++) {
            updatePensionerData(pensionerExcel, pensionerDB, pathDB, i, j);
            if (pensionerExcel.get(i).getPensionInsuranceNumber() == pensionerDB.get(j).getPensionInsuranceNumber() && pensionerExcel.get(i).getStatusOld() != pensionerDB.get(j).getStatusOld()) {
                checkStatusChange = true;
                pensionerDB.get(j).setStatusNew(pensionerDB.get(j).getStatusOld());
                pensionerDB.get(j).setStatusOld(pensionerExcel.get(i).getStatusOld());
                result.add(pensionerDB.get(j));
                break;
            } else if (pensionerExcel.get(i).getPensionInsuranceNumber() == pensionerDB.get(j).getPensionInsuranceNumber() && pensionerExcel.get(i).getStatusOld() == pensionerDB.get(j).getStatusOld()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Database.close();

}

public void updatePensionerData(List<Pensioner> pensionerExcel, List<Pensioner> pensionerDB, String pathDB, int i, int j) {
    if (pensionerExcel.get(i).getPensionInsuranceNumber() == pensionerDB.get(j).getPensionInsuranceNumber()) {
        if (pensionerExcel.get(i).getIdkz() != pensionerDB.get(j).getIdkz()) {
            Database.updateIdkz(pensionerExcel.get(i), pathDB);
        }
        if (!pensionerExcel.get(i).getCompany().equals(pensionerDB.get(j).getCompany())) {
            Database.updateCompany(pensionerExcel.get(i), pathDB);
        }
        if (pensionerExcel.get(i).getPersonelId() != pensionerDB.get(j).getPersonelId()) {
            Database.updatePersonelId(pensionerExcel.get(i), pathDB);
        }

        if (!pensionerExcel.get(i).getBirthDate().isEqual(pensionerDB.get(j).getBirthDate())) {
            Database.updateBirthDate(pensionerExcel.get(i), pathDB);
        }
        //...
        //26 more if statements for the other values
        //...
    }
}
```

}

My database methods:

```
public static void updateIdkz(Pensioner p, String pathDB) {
    String update = String.format("UPDATE Pensionär SET idkz = ?");
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(update);
        ps.setInt(1, p.getIdkz());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void updatePersonelId(Pensioner p, String pathDB) {
    String update = String.format("UPDATE Pensionär SET PersNr = ? Where pknr = ?");
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(update);
        ps.setInt(1, p.getPersonelId());
        ps.setInt(2, p.getPensionInsuranceNumber());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void updateBirthDate(Pensioner p, String pathDB) {
    String update = String.format("UPDATE Pensionär SET Geburtsdatum = ? Where pknr = ?");
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(update);
        ps.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(p.getBirthDate()));
        ps.setInt(2, p.getPensionInsuranceNumber());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one question... Why those `String.format`?

Comment: I think I saw it somewhere in an example when I read something about prepared statements and thought it would be good to use. But your question indicates its not useful I guess?

Comment: Oh wait I actually used it when I had some other statements with some format specifiers and I just didnt delete the String.format part

Comment: Try creating your PreparedStatements once and re-using them rather than re-creating the prepared statements in each method. Also, as Gurwinder says, ditch the `String.format()` because it will try to parse the string each time.

Comment: @xtratic isnt this what I am doing? I mean I created it at the top of my full code like this: public static PreparedStatement ps; and using the same preparedStatement ps afterwards in my methods.

Comment: You are leaking statements on each method invocation. Either properly close them, or make sure you reuse them correctly. This may (or may not) contribute to your problem.

Comment: @wenzel267 no you are not reusing the same `PreparedStatements` you are reusing the *variable* but constantly creating new `PreparedStatement` objects to put in it. `ps = connection.prepareStatement(update);` creates a new `PreparedStatement` object, overwriting the existing one in that variable `ps`.

Comment: You could also do batch transactions if you are calling a the same PreparedStatement many times in a row.

Comment: @xtratic so for reusing the same preparedStatement instead of creating a new one I only have to use the code connection.prepareStatement(update); without the  'ps = '? is that correct?

Comment: @wenzel267 No, incorrect. `connection.prepareStatement(update);` creates a new `PreparedStatement` object every time. So by calling that method multiple times, you are just creating new `PreparedStatement`s and not reusing them. See my answer for what you can do for both reusing the same Statements, batching your updates, and ensuring your Statements are closed when you are done with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will be more efficient. You can re-use the PreparedStatements and even batch the updates to make the transactions faster. Also, as others have said, remember to close your PreparedStatements.

```
class Test implements Closeable {

    // reusable PreparedStatements
    private final PreparedStatement updateIdkz;
    private final PreparedStatement updatePersonelId;
    private final PreparedStatement updateBirthDate;

    public Test(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        this.updateIdkz = con
            .prepareStatement("UPDATE Pensionär SET idkz = ?");
        this.updatePersonelId = con
            .prepareStatement("UPDATE Pensionär SET PersNr = ? Where pknr = ?");
        this.updateBirthDate = con
            .prepareStatement("UPDATE Pensionär SET Geburtsdatum = ? Where pknr = ?");
    }

    /** Closes all the prepared statements. */
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            updateIdkz.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        try {
            updatePersonelId.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        try {
            updateBirthDate.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }

    public void addBatchUpdateIdkz(Pensioner p) {
        try {
            updateIdkz.clearParameters();
            updateIdkz.setInt(1, p.getIdkz());
            updateIdkz.addBatch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addBatchUpdatePersonelId(Pensioner p) {
        try {
            updatePersonelId.clearParameters();
            updatePersonelId.setInt(1, p.getPersonelId());
            updatePersonelId.setInt(2, p.getPensionInsuranceNumber());
            updatePersonelId.addBatch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addBatchUpdateBirthDate(Pensioner p) {
        try {
            updateBirthDate.clearParameters();
            updateBirthDate.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(p.getBirthDate()));
            updateBirthDate.setInt(2, p.getPensionInsuranceNumber());
            updateBirthDate.addBatch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void executeBatchUpdateIdkz() throws SQLException {
        updateIdkz.executeBatch();
    }

    public void executeBatchUpdatePersonelId() throws SQLException {
        updatePersonelId.executeBatch();
    }

    public void executeBatchUpdateBirthDate() throws SQLException {
        updateBirthDate.executeBatch();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pensioner p1 = null, p2 = null, p3 = null, p4 = null;
        Connection con = null;

        // try with resources to ensure you close the prepared statements
        try (Test t = new Test(con);) {
            // Update multiple Idkz
            t.addBatchUpdateIdkz(p1);
            t.addBatchUpdateIdkz(p2);
            t.addBatchUpdateIdkz(p3);
            t.addBatchUpdateIdkz(p4);
            t.executeBatchUpdateIdkz();

            // Update multile PersonelId
            t.addBatchUpdatePersonelId(p1);
            t.addBatchUpdatePersonelId(p2);
            t.addBatchUpdatePersonelId(p3);
            t.addBatchUpdatePersonelId(p4);
            t.executeBatchUpdatePersonelId();

            // etc...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `finally` block for each `try... catch` and close the PreparedStatement object.

Example:

```
public static void updateIdkz(Pensioner p, String pathDB) {
  String update = String.format("UPDATE Pensionär SET idkz = ?");
  try {
      ps = connection.prepareStatement(update);
      ps.setInt(1, p.getIdkz());
      ps.executeUpdate();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally {
    ps.close();
  }
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It would be better to use try-with-resource. And although you're right to point out this problem with the OP's code, it doesn't really answer the question. It would have been better as a comment.